# How to order/sort data frame by month?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I made this data frame with monthly precipitation data for many years (1961-2019). But somehow my dataframe ended up like a mess (check the picture). Is  there any way to sort my data by month? For some reason I got first April, then November, June, etc and I do not know how to change it.

[image]

Comment: April 1961 1.5100000
2 August 1961 1.2935484
3 December 1961 3.6580645
4 February 1961 2.9821429
5 January 1961 5.0000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
## create data
month <- c('April','August', 'December', 'February')
year <- c(1961, 1961, 1962, 1962)
pp <- c(1.51,1.239,3.658,2.982)
df <- cbind.data.frame(month, year, pp)
```

So the data looks like this

```
     month year    pp
1    April 1961 1.510
2   August 1961 1.239
3 December 1962 3.658
4 February 1962 2.982
```

And now we can create a date to sort by

```
## create date
df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$month, '01', df$year), format="%b %d %Y")

## sort dataframe by date
df <- df[order(df$date),]
```

Which results in this:

```
     month year    pp       date
1    April 1961 1.510 1961-04-01
2   August 1961 1.239 1961-08-01
4 February 1962 2.982 1962-02-01
3 December 1962 3.658 1962-12-01
```

If you do not care for the year you can match the month name to the actual number related to that month and sort on that instead, like this:

```
df$month_number <- match(df$month,month.name)
df[order(df$month_number),]
```

which would give you this:

```
     month year    pp       date
4 February 1962 2.982 1962-02-01
1    April 1961 1.510 1961-04-01
2   August 1961 1.239 1961-08-01
3 December 1962 3.658 1962-12-01
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to try something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Here I made a DataFrame with the sample date you post
data=[("April", 1961, 1.5100000  ),("August", 1961, 1.2935484 ),("December", 1961, 3.6580645  ),("February", 1961, 2.9821429 ),("January", 1961, 5.0000000),("January", 1962, 6.0000000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["month", "year", "prec"])

# So we create a new datetime column from your month and year
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str)+df.month,format= '%Y%B')

# And finally we sort it!
df.sort_values('date')
```

And the result is this

```
      month  year      prec       date
4   January  1961  5.000000 1961-01-01
3  February  1961  2.982143 1961-02-01
0     April  1961  1.510000 1961-04-01
1    August  1961  1.293548 1961-08-01
2  December  1961  3.658065 1961-12-01
5   January  1962  6.000000 1962-01-01
```

**Note:**

If you want to sort exclusively by month, you can change the month column to its numerical value, with the next code:

```py
df['month']=pd.to_datetime(df.month,format= '%B').dt.month
df.sort_values('month')
```

And you'll get

```
   month  year      prec
4      1  1961  5.000000
5      1  1962  6.000000
3      2  1961  2.982143
0      4  1961  1.510000
1      8  1961  1.293548
2     12  1961  3.658065
```

Comment: Got it but how can I use pd.DataFrame function in R Studio? Is there any package I need to download?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen you are working on R. So you can create the month or datetime column by using `strptime` like this: `df[['date']] <- strptime(df[['month']], format='%Y.%B')`. I haven't R installed so I can't test it :(. Let me know if it works.